# multiplexing unnamed pipe and other file descriptors using select

Tags: c++, c, linux, select, pipe

I'm trying to multiplex an unnamed pipe with some other file descriptors.
The problem is that the pipe file descriptor always appears in the result of `select`. In other words the event-loop reads from pipe for infinite times. Here is a metaphor of what I want to do, and what actually happens.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace std;
int main(){
    fd_set master;    // master file descriptor list
    fd_set read_fds;  // temp file descriptor list for select() 
    FD_ZERO(&master);    // clear the master and temp sets
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    int fdmax;        // maximum file descriptor number
    int pfd[2];
    if(pipe(pfd)!=0) {cout<<"Unable to create a pipe.\n",exit(1);};

    FD_SET(0, &master);
    FD_SET(pfd[0],&master);

    fdmax=pfd[0];

    if(fork()){//Parent


        for (;;){
            read_fds = master; // copy it
            if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
                perror("select");
                exit(4);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
                if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {
                    int n;
                    char buff[200];

                    if (i==pfd[0]){
                        close(pfd[1]);
                        n=read(pfd[0],buff,sizeof(buff));
                        buff[n]=0;
                        cout<<"Read from pipe:"<<buff<<endl;
                    }else if(i==0){
                        n=read(0,buff,sizeof(buff));
                        buff[n]=0;
                        cout<<"Read from std:"<<buff<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }else{//Child
        usleep(50000);
        char buff[200]="This is a simple sample.";
        close(pfd[0]);
        write(pfd[1],buff,sizeof(buff));
        close(pfd[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot reuse fd sets across the calls to `select`. Reinitialize `read_fds` in the loop.

Comment: @user58697  line `read_fds = master;` reinitialize `read_fds` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `read()` call can read less than number of bytes specified in the last argument ant id does not automatically append zero-byte terminator, so your receiving code can easily access uninitialized memory in buff[] and after it (if there is no zero byte). You **need to check return value when calling `read`** and use only so many bytes from buffer.

Then, the `select` call returns when any file descriptor in the `readfds` set won't block on subsequent read. Which includes end-of-file condition. This likely happens in your case, when the forked process closes its fd. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425938/using-eof-for-signaling-on-unnamed-pipes) too.

Could it be the reason for the problem you encounter? Checking return value when calling `read` make this clear to you, as read returns zero if-and-only-if the fd reached end of file.

Last detail – it does not make much sense to close `pfd[1]` only after `pfd[0]` is returned in the `readfds`. You should close it immediately after the fork, so it remains open in the child process only if you have no use for it in the parent process.

Comment: Thank to your brave answer you were right about the returned value of `read`. It returns zero for several times. **I shouldn't close `pfd[0]`**. About closing `pfd[1]`, as you said, it would be better to close it once right after fork in the parent process, although it would n't bother in this case.

Comment: I never told you should close pfd[0], I believe. About pfd[1], note that not closing it in time may affect if/how EOF event is received. Not especially critical in your piece of code, but in general, when child process would not push any data in the pipe but terminated directly (for whichever reason), your parent process won't see any event, neither EOF as it holds its own copy of pfd[1] open (I assume, feel free to check details on EOF and closing pipe fds yourself).